# HTTP request header field "optdata"

Tags: http, drm

So, I googled a lot but couldn't find a HTTP request header field called "**optdata**". I am working on allowing the user to watch DRM protected videos on chromecast device. I am following a document from drmtoday.com which says:

> For Widevine, the metadata must be carried inside the “optdata” field,
>   inside the HTTP request header with name “dt-custom-data” or
>   “x-dt-custom-data”.

I understand that the header key name is "dt-custom-data" but couldn't find any reference explaining what exactly is **optdata**.

If I just encode the following data to base64 and pass it as 'dt-custom-data' header, the request fails saying that '**HTTP Status 412 - Precondition failed**'.

{
  "userId":"12345",
  "sessionId":"RWFzdGVyZWdn",
  "merchant":"a-merchant"
}

Answer (score 0):

It just means that `dt-custom-data` and `x-dt-custom-data` headers support key/value pairs. `optdata` is a recognised key.

E.g.

```
dt-custom-data: optdata={ "userId":"12345", "sessionId":"RWFzdGVyZWdn", "merchant":"a-merchant" }
```